# Im trying to bind my left mouse button to the compose key

Tags: bind

I already created the .xbindkeysrc file containing the following:

> "xdotool mousedown 1"
>       Super_R "xdotool mouseup 1"
>       Super_R + Release

it partially works but when I press the key, is as if the button was held, not just a regular click